# Sysaid database supporting clustering

Tags: ticket-system

I am facing multiple issues on my second DB cluster, every time, being caused by a process that is suspended on the first DB cluster. This happens with the Sysaid system DB.
Does Sysaid support clustering ?
https://documentation.sysaid.com/docs/database-guide

I tried killing the suspended process and it worked but I would like to do this efficiently next time.